# Не могу создать страницу в WP

Tags: wordpress

очень нужна помощь, удалил страницу Services, надо создать такую же страницу с таким же названием Service в WP. Но при создании страницу вообще не видно только сам сайт, убираешь одну букву или меняешь на русскую одну букву все работает страница подгружается с шаблонам. Как решить проблему ?

Comment: Если при переходе на страницу открывается главная, значит, у Вас в теме нет шаблона страницы page.php, который отвечает за вывод страниц. Его надо создать, в нём прописать разметку и логику вывода контента

Comment: Есть, я создал и выбрал. Создаю новую страницу убираю Services букву s и все работает. В чем проблема ?

Comment: Что значит "выбрал"? page.php - это базовый шаблон страницы по умолчанию, его не надо выбирать.